# Fade in and out depending on div id

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code to distinct between two divs

```
$("#addresslink").click(function() {
    $("#main").find("div").each(function(n,i){
        var id = this.id;
        if(id == "addressdiv")
        {
            $('#' + id).fadeIn(300);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });

});


$("#storylink").click(function() {
    $("#main").find("div").each(function(n,i){
        var id = this.id;
        if(id == "storydiv")
        {
            $('#' + id).fadeIn(300);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(250);
        }    
    });

});
```

is there a better way to tie a  to a div rather than hardcoding each  to a  then showing and hiding the other divs?

P.S: I have done the code just asking whether could i optimize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to optimize without changing anything is move the common code to function:

```
$("#addresslink").click(function() {
   fadeDiv('addressdiv');
});

$("#storylink").click(function() {
    fadeDiv('storydiv');     
});

function fadeDiv(divName) {
  $("#main").find("div").each(function(n,i){
            var id = this.id;
            if(id == divName)
            {
                $('#' + id).fadeIn(300);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#' + id).fadeOut(250);
            }    
        });
}
```

OR

you can also do this :

```
$("#addresslink,#storylink").click(function() {
    fadeDiv(($(this).attr('id')=='addresslink')?'addressdiv':'storydiv');
});

function fadeDiv(divName) {
  $("#main").find("div").each(function(n,i){
            var id = this.id,
$id = $('#' + id);
            (id == divName)? $id.fadeIn(300):$id.fadeOut(250);
        });
}​
```

Comment: thanks so much, still not very clear on the function code for jquery. thanks  :D do you happened to have code for a switch case in jquery?

Comment: Function here takes the divName depending on which div/button you clicked, once it gets the div name it checks for that div name and once it is matched it fades in that div.

I didnt ran into any issue where i need to use switch case.  But it depends if its required you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean :

```
$("#addresslink, #storylink").click(function() {
    $("#main").find("div").each(function(n,i){
        var id = this.id;
        if(id == "addressdiv")
        {
            $('#' + id).fadeIn(300);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: then what will happen if i click storylink and want to show the story div? yea maybe something like a switch case will be good, but i am still new to jquery.